# Extending stay in the Schengen area to travel to a new country within the approved period

Tags: schengen-visas, spain, iceland

I recently got my visa approved for a visit to Iceland (issued by the embassy of Denmark since they process the visa applications for Iceland in the country I applied from). My plan was to stay in Iceland for 10 days and the visa I got allows me to stay in Schengen countries for 15 days, single entry. I'm thinking of using the extra 5 days to visit Spain and return from Spain instead of returning from Iceland. Will that be okay or should I be concerned about this having a negative impact on my visa?

Answer (score 4):

That’s fine, but:

- Make sure you don’t travel via the UK or Ireland (or any other non-Schengen country), as that would mean exiting and then re-entering the Schengen area, which you can’t do as you have a single-entry visa;
- Try to avoid leaving on the very last day of validity of your visa, as if there are any issues with your flight or you getting to the airport timely this could cause you to overstay. Keep some margin.
- Remember that any day during which you are in the Schengen Area counts as a full day, even if you are there only 5 minutes. So your first and last day in Schengen count as full days.
- Make sure you don’t further change your plans and end up spending more time in Spain (or another Schengen country) than you do in Iceland.